# Passport-local-mongoose how to get authentication error message?

Tags: mongoose, passport-local

I am using passport-local-mongoose for local authentication and cannot find a way to display authentication error message. The only mention of error messages in their documentation is in regard to overriding the default ones.

How can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of digging, finally found that error messages can be accessed via `error` key on `flash()`:

```
router.get('/login',
    function(req, res) {
        res.render('login', { user: req.user, message: req.flash('error') });
    });
```